# How to change homepage based on cookies?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have landing page when user hit the base URL

> example: http://127.0.0.1/footwear/

user will redirect to the landing page and there is link as

> ENTER THERE WEBSITE

- once user click on enter there website its redirect to the main website .
- I need to set cookies for particular time when user revisit the base URL landing page after particular time period so user can direct to the redirect to the main website not landing page.

how can achieve this ?
Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento event for this task

in your case you can use `controller_action_predispatch` event

If you dont know how to write event then you can take refrence to this article

http://inchoo.net/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/

and then you can check your cookie in this event and redirect user to some other page you can take refrence of this article how you can redirect to user

https://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-url-redirect-from-controller/